# How to disable toolbar at the bottom of WebKit View

Tags: ios, css, swift

I have a ***UIWebKit*** View inside of my view that loads a dashboard I've created.

However, an input tag within the view is triggering a toolbar to be displayed at the bottom of my view as shown in the image. The toolbar only displays if the input tag is clicked. I've tried disabling touch and selection in the CSS of the dashboard I'm loading by:

```
* {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

but that still did not resolve the issue. I was wondering if it is possible to just suppress or disable this toolbar from displaying at the bottom of my view. I'm using ***Swift 4*** and Xcode 9.2.

[image: The toolbar that displays at the bottom of my view]

How can I get ride of this toolbar triggered from my **WebView** ?

Answer (score 0):

You are testing this into a simulator, isn't it?

I'm afraid that it's not only a toolbar appearing, but a whole keyboard.
Keyboard is not always displayed, but you can make it appear by pressing:

> ⌘ + K

So maybe, this will change bit your question?

Comment: Correct it's in a simulator. I tried using ⌘ + K but it didn't toggle the keyboard though.

Comment: @SpartanEngr1297,  When you did the test, can you confirm me that your input field had the focus, and your toolbar was present ?

Comment: yeah it has the focus and the toolbar then opens and it won't let me scroll on the WebView until I click done on the toolbar

Comment: @SpartanEngr1297, this behaviour is confusing to me. My last suggest would be to test on a real iPhone device. This ways, you should be able to see the entire keyboard.